# Calling a template part from a post

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I would like to include an iFrame within a post in WordPress. I would like it to be located inside the content of the post, meaning I cannot just but it in the post template file, otherwise it will be either before or after.

I'd like to add the Facebook plugin within the posts:

```
<div id="socialWrap"><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://onlinearizonahomes.info"   data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"></div></div>
```

I am thinking of calling a template part within my post `<?php get_template_part( 'social' ); ?>` but I cannot use PHP within a post without a plugin (I'd like to avoid using a plugin for this).

An alternative would be using JavaScript to create the HTML in the post, but this seems like an unnecessary use of JavaScript.

What is the best way to add HTML within a WordPress post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Shortcode.

**Add functions.php**

```
function cudjex_fbshare( $atts, $content = null ) { 
    global $post;
    $link = get_permalink($post->ID);
    return '<div id="socialWrap"><div class="fb-like" data-href="'.$link.'"   data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"></div></div>'; 
} 
add_shortcode('fb_share', 'cudjex_fbshare');
```

**Usage :**
Hello world, [fb_share] !

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is using a [Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)